# I need to fill the whole cell of region without title with color

Tags: html, css, oracle-apex

I need to fill the whole cell which is based on a particular count sql with a color depending on the quantity returned .

**The Solution i tried:**

pl/sql that gives a background_color substitution string based on count.
This string is passed in column formatting atributes as in following code

```
<table>
  <td WIDTH=30 HEIGHT=30 onclick="window.open('http://page.com" bgcolor=#BG_COLOR# >#COUNT(*)#</td>
</table>
```

page.com is the page that displays the all results (not count) of the sql in the same window

**Problem:**

The whole cell is not getting filled up with the color. May be the cell can be resized or some thing could be done

Comment: @your code is broken. Provide unbroken snippets of code please. Also, using css property `background-color: #BG_COLOR#` may help things a bit.

Comment: Is this cell a cell in a standard report, interactive report, markup you generate yourself or markup you added in the sql of a standard/interactive report?

Comment: @bPratik Where do I add this background-color:#BG_COLOR# as i have already added it to the colum formatting attributes .

Comment: @Tom this is a standard report . I m just showing  count using a sql query in a region without title template . I need the background of the region to be colored based on the count .

Answer (score 0):

You might solve this by using a report, but it will require some javascript/dynamic action to actually make the background of the cell change. Your cell will not be filled a 100% even when you generate some html code, because it too will be wrapped in the html structure of the report (ie, a TD element).
You could create a new report template (shared components > templates), but even then you'd still have to generate some html code in your sql.

If you only have 1 record and 1 cell and ultimately need to generate some html in it, then i'd not use a report region actually. Use a PLSQL region and generate your bit of HTML in it. For example:

```
DECLARE
   lCount NUMBER;
   lColour VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
   SELECT count(*)
     INTO lCount
     FROM emp;

   IF lCount < 10 THEN
      lColour := 'blue';
   ELSIF lCount > 10 THEN
      lColour := 'red';
   END IF;

   htp.p('div style="background-color: '||lColour||'; width: 30px; height: 30px;">'||lCount||'</div>');
END;
```

You'd maybe have to change the region template though to completely fit your needs. You could always copy one and change it so it has minimal impact on the html you generate.